# Is it possible to ignore the dependency hash validation of just one module (or registry)?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

The `yarn.lock` file saves all the dependencies versions and the hashes of the modules. I know that I can globally disable this hash checking with the option `--skip-integrity-check`.

We have an internal module that is continually developed. The dependency is really of a snapshot package. When it is updated, it fails in our continuous integration environment because the updated package hash is different of the yarn.lock saved hash.

Is it possible to disable the integrity check just for a specific module?

I'll accept the answer even if it tells how to disable the check for all the modules of a specific registry.

**Update:** My problem is that my continuous integration server job is breaking when the dependency is updated, even if there's no modification in my code. These are spurious failings and I want to stop them.

**Update 2:** The accepted solution is really a hack to solve a problem in a usual development workflow. There is an [issue open for Yarn in GitHub](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2314) to fix this problem.

Comment: Instead of disabling integrity check, could you not run `yarn upgrade <your package>` to synchronise your lockfile to the latest available module snapshot?

Comment: @mrblewog: I've changed the question to make it clearer. The problem is my continuous integration server.

Comment: Noted - and I don’t know the answer I’m afraid!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of running

```
yarn install
```

You should run it like below

```
yarn add <specificpackage>@^<versions> --update-checksums
yarn install
```

This will make sure that the `yarn.lock` is updated with latest hash for that package and then `yarn install` will install the rest of the packages with integrity check

**Update-1: 20-April**

Another possible options is to use the `preinstall` hook. There are few things you can try here. You can try updating the package. But be aware that launching the `yarn` command again in `preinstall` can cause infinite loops.

So better way may be to run a `grep`, `awk` or a `sed` command and get ride of the package entry in the `yarn.lock` file. This will make sure the `yarn install` command has no information on the hash and a mismatch can't occur

If you don't want to use `awk`, `sed` or `grep` because of windows compatibility then you should just write a simple nodejs script to get rid of the package from the `yarn.lock` file. This will cross-os compatible. Below code shows how to do the same

**yarn_remove_hash.js**

```
const fs = require('fs')

const content = fs.readFileSync("yarn.lock", "utf-8");
const packageToDelete = "yallist"

let lines = content.split("\n")

for (let [i, line] of Object.entries(lines)) {
    if (line.startsWith(packageToDelete + "@")) {
        lines[i]="";
        let y = i;
        while (lines[++y][0] ==" "){
            lines[y]= ""
        }
    }
}

fs.writeFileSync("yarn.lock", lines.join("\n"))
```

And you will update your `scripts` section in `package.json` like below

```
...
"preinstall": "node yarn_remove_hash.js"
...
```

Comment: I want it to stop checking the check sum. This will fix it once, but when the package is updated (it is a package in development), it will fail again. I want to prevent the need to update the hash sum everytime so my continous integration won't fail.

Comment: Doesn't the CI checkout the package and always do a fresh install?

Comment: yes, but the yarn.lock file becomes inconsistent with the dependency package in your nexus repository. So it fails. @Tarun Lalwani

Comment: Please join [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169375/discussion-for-49501749-yarn-is-it-possible-to-ignore-the-dependency-hash-validat) chat room

Comment: I need to run `node yarn_remove_hash.js` separately because yarn reads the yarn.lock file before running the preinstall script.

Comment: Node v12 works as is.  Node v16 seems to keep the first load of `yarn.lock` in memory throughout the hooks, so further modifications aren't naturally seen by Yarn.  However, if you update it to be `"preinstall": "node yarn_remove_hash.js && yarn install --ignore-scripts"`, it seems to load the modified `yarn.lock` into memory and in my case was able to continue as expected.  I couldn't find a more specialized command to do the same unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make @Tarun Lalwani's --update-checksums more of a transparent process for you and others, you can add the following to `.yarnrc`:

```
--install.update-checksums true
```

Now when a user runs `yarn install` it will also update checksums implicitly.  This was needed for me because one of my dependencies is linked to a snapshot .tar.gz that changes and NPM/Yarn would assume that it wouldn't, obviously leading us to this integrity issue.  I had to move away from NPM because of this and also tried the preinstall hook (I thought I was clever but I guess you guys did the same).
At least Yarn has an option around this.  Tarun's updated answer did not work for me either because yarn.lock is checked against before any hooks are ran.